# Win32 - Subclassing Rich Edit

Tags: c++, winapi

I'm trying to create a Windows desktop app which has a Rich Edit control, and I want to handle certain keystrokes within the control e.g. hitting enter will execute some code based on what's been typed on that line, similar to a console app. I started with the regular Windows Desktop App template in Visual Studio, and created my control within the WndProc:

```
case WM_CREATE:
        {
            LoadLibrary(TEXT("Msftedit.dll"));

            //Console creation
            hwndEdit = CreateWindowEx(
                WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE, // extended styles
                MSFTEDIT_CLASS,  // Predefined class
                NULL,      // text 
                WS_TABSTOP | WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_VSCROLL |
                ES_LEFT | ES_MULTILINE | ES_AUTOVSCROLL,  // Styles 
                0,         // x position - size and position handled separately
                0,         // y position 
                0,        // Button width
                0,        // Button height
                hWnd,     // Parent window
                (HMENU)ID_CONSOLE,       // Control ID
                (HINSTANCE)GetWindowLongPtr(hWnd, GWLP_HINSTANCE),
                NULL);      // Pointer not needed           
        }
        break;
```

So far, so good. However, when I try to create a procedure for the control and attach it, it doesn't seem to do anything and to be honest, based on the documentation and a lot of Google searches, I'm still not entirely sure how it should be done. My procedure looks like the below:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK EditControlProc(HWND hWnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam, UINT_PTR uIdSubclass, DWORD_PTR dwRefData)
{
    //static HWND hwndEdit;
    switch (uMsg)
    {
        case WM_PAINT:
            return TRUE;
            // Other cases...
        case WM_KEYDOWN:
            switch (wParam)
            {
                case VK_RETURN:
                    MessageBox(NULL, L"You pressed enter!", L"Title", NULL);
            }
        /*case WM_CREATE:
        {
            HWND console = GetDlgItem(hWnd, ID_CONSOLE);
            SetWindowSubclass(console, EditControlProc, 0, 0);
            return TRUE;
        }*/

    }
    return DefSubclassProc(hWnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
}
```

and my attempt to attach that to the control (which I based on the example [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/win32/controls/subclassing-overview?redirectedfrom=MSDN)) was:

```
case WM_CREATE:
        {
            HWND console = GetDlgItem(hWnd, ID_CONSOLE);
            SetWindowSubclass(console, EditControlProc, 0, 0);
            return TRUE;
        }
```

I tried handling this within various messages (the last of which was WM_CREATE as above - the link shows WM_INITDIALOG but that didn't work) with no success, and to be honest I'm not sure where I should add this in my case.
I know this is a really basic question and I feel like there should be loads of examples to show me how it's done and I might just be making a stupid mistake (far from unheard of in my short programming studentship), but I've been searching for days and haven't found what I'm looking for so would really appreciate a pointer or two.

Thanks!

Comment: When you call `GetDlgItem(hWnd, ID_CONSOLE);`, `hWnd` is the edit control itself. You're telling it to look in the child windows of the edit control to find `ID_CONSOLE`, which of course is failing. You need to install the subclass immediately after you actually create the edit control (e.g. in the window procedure for the parent window). `hwndEdit` is the edit control you want to sub-class, so you would simply call `SetWindowSubclass(hwndEdit , EditControlProc, 0, 0);`.

Comment: @JonathanPotter thanks for commenting. I added the SetWindowSubclass directly after creating the control as you suggested. That seems to have stopped me being able to interact with the controls at all - I can't click into and type in the edit control and a button that is also part of the UI, which was previously working fine, now does nothing when I click on it. Is there something wrong with the edit control procedure?

Comment: Well in the code you posted, you're intercepting `WM_PAINT` and returning immediately - thus stopping the control from doing any painting at all. Your subproc should only change the behaviour it needs to change.

Comment: Thanks, that was it! Removing the WM_PAINT handler fixed it. Thanks again!